# Заполнение базы данных postgresql при помощи ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Мне нужно написать код, который при запуске будет заполнять бд. Написаны модели, репозитории, сервисы, дтошки и Datainitializer. При запуске выводится ошибка: Error creating SQL create commands for table : brand. В прошлом я уже видел данную ошибку, проблема была в том, что в BaseEntity я указал id как uuid, а в дтошках как int. Я поменял всё на id и проблема решилась. Сейчас я все переписал под uuid и данная проблема опять вылезла. Везде указано uuid, но всё равно не могу найти решения.
Модели и дтошки привожу ниже:
BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    protected UUID uuid;

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

Brand:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "brand")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Brand extends BaseEntity{
    @Column(name = "name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String name; //наименование бренда
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate created; //дата и время
    @Column(name = "modified", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate modified; //дата и время

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Model> model;

    protected Brand() {

    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "model")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Model extends BaseEntity{
    @Column(name = "name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String name; //имя модели
    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private Category category;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl", length = 60)
    private String imageUrl; //ссылка на юрл
    @Column(name = "startYear", nullable = false)
    private int startYear;
    @Column(name = "endYear", nullable = false)
    private int endYear;
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate created;
    @Column(name = "modified", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate modified;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable=false)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Brand brand;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "offer_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable=false)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Offer offer;

    protected Model() {

    }
}
```

BrandDTO

```
@Data
public class BrandDto {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name; //наименование бренда

    private LocalDate created; //дата и время
    private LocalDate modified; //дата и время

    public BrandDto() {

    }

    public BrandDto(String name, LocalDate created, LocalDate modified) {
        this.name = name;
        this.created = created;
        this.modified = modified;
    }

}
```

ModelDTO

```
@Data
public class ModelDto {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name; //имя модели

    private Category category;

    private String imageUrl; //ссылка на юрл

    private int startYear;

    private int endYear;

    private LocalDate created;

    private LocalDate modified;
    private BrandDto brand;

    private OfferDto offer;

    public ModelDto() {

    }

    public ModelDto(String name, Category category, String imageUrl, int startYear, int endYear, LocalDate created, LocalDate modified, BrandDto brand, OfferDto offer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.startYear = startYear;
        this.endYear = endYear;
        this.created = created;
        this.modified = modified;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.offer = offer;
    }
}
```

Более полный лог ошибки:

```
2023-10-19T02:02:48.199+03:00 ERROR 7516 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : brand
2023-10-19T02:02:48.200+03:00  WARN 7516 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : brand
2023-10-19T02:02:48.202+03:00  INFO 7516 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-10-19T02:02:48.208+03:00  INFO 7516 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-10-19T02:02:48.258+03:00 ERROR 7516 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : brand
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую добавить `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)` над `id`, так как uuid могут по-разному храниться в БД. Однако с этим есть проблема с кастомными запросами - надо передавать `uuid.toString()` вместо обычного объекта.